# Question about this slang/curse word

Tags: translation, meaning, slang

While translating a novel, I came across the following dialogue:

“혹시 제가 아는 그, 시벌좌?”

“……인터넷 방송 보셨나 봐요.”

차라리 산서잠룡이 낫겠다. 시벌좌가 뭐야, 시벌좌가.

The phrase "시벌좌" from the first line seems to have potentially offensive undertones, which has made it challenging for me to translate since I cannot find an equivalent English word.

Would anyone be able to provide a direct translation of "시벌좌"? I'm seeking an accurate representation, regardless of its potential offensiveness.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

That word is an insult to the deceased.

Park Won-soon
https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%94%A8%EB%B0%9C%EB%A0%A8%EC%95%84

Answer (score 1):

시벌좌 is a combination of 시벌+좌.

시벌 is a variation of 씨발, which is the most commonly used curse in Korean. The usage and meaning 씨발 are very close to 'fuck' in English.

Meanwhile, 좌 is another slang for a title, which can be translated as `The one who ...`, `Mr.`, `Ms.`, or whatever. Its origin is 본좌, which is a first-person singular pronoun mostly used by high class people in chivalric novels with the background of pre-modern China. Using '-좌' is not that popular on the Korean web these days; but sometimes you still may be able to find this.

Thus, 시벌좌 indicates that the person who is described with this word is going viral for saying `시벌` or `씨발` in some situations.